# Why do you divide an odd length array by 2 to get the middle array?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to Java and I am currently doing exercises on coding bat. For a problem (posted below), I was wondering why you would divide the length of the array by 2 to get the middle array?

Question:
"Given an array of ints of odd length, look at the first, last, and middle values in the array and return the largest. The array length will be a least 1."

Comment: Because arrays in Java are zero based. First entry of array a would be a[0] and integer division rounds down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr.length` will return an integer. When you divide an integer by an integer, you will get an integer that will round down. If you have a 5-element array: 1 2 3 4 5. The middle element will be 3. It will do 5/2. We know this equals 2.5. However, since we divided an int by an int, it will just return 2. Indeed, the element with an index of 2 in the array is 3, the middle element.

Comment: Good answer. *Oddly*, there is no exact middle of an even-lengthed array, but we live with using the element preceding the mid point because it allows using the same arithmetic for all non-empty arrays.